# Html code parsed on desktop, but not parsed on mobile viewing?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

Site: http://createconnectionsinc.com/test/

If you look at the website on desktop view, it looks fine.

If you look at it on mobile viewing, you will see that the logo shrinks, the menu section disappears, and the rest of the site just narrows down in width.

Screenshot of mobile view: http://screencast.com/t/NIbD8ONaDn

Not sure why the code for the menu is not parsed....it's blurred out unlike the logo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the collapse navbar bootstrap component. By default this is hidden at the mobile defined breakpoint and is used in combination with the navbar-toggle button to collapse/expand the navigation menu.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

> **Requires JavaScript plugin**
>
> If JavaScript is disabled and the viewport
> is narrow enough that the navbar collapses, it will be impossible to
> expand the navbar and view the content within the .navbar-collapse.
>
> The responsive navbar requires the collapse plugin to be included in
> your version of Bootstrap.
>
> **Changing the collapsed mobile navbar breakpoint**
>
> The navbar collapses into its vertical mobile view when the
> viewport is narrower than @grid-float-breakpoint, and expands into its
> horizontal non-mobile view when the viewport is at least
> @grid-float-breakpoint in width. Adjust this variable in the Less
> source to control when the navbar collapses/expands. The default value
> is 768px (the smallest "small" or "tablet" screen).

Comment: Wow, I did not know that.  I never saw the vertical navbar.  Will have to investigate it further.  Thank you!

Comment: Working on getting the menu to shop on a dropdown menu which actually shows up on mobile view.  Problem is, it also shows up on desktop view.  How would I modify the code so that one code is parsed in desktop view and another code gets parsed on mobile.  I know you can do  (at)media for adjusting CSS for mobile viewing but how about html?

Comment: Try using the class 'visible-xs' on the mobile menu and 'hidden-xs' on the other one.

Comment: Another question:  I have a css property.  I want it to have one value in desktop view and a different value on mobile view.  But on mobile view, it still shows it as it would look in desktop view.

Comment: So this is when you need to use media queries. I like to take a mobile first approach where i write my css to cater for all and then introduce media queries to overwrite/add to those classes as the media gets wider. for example: .my-class {color:red} @media(min-width:768px){.my-class{color:orange}} So here, once the media is wider than 767px, the color property changes from red to orange.

Comment: doesn't that code make your color orange when its within 768 pixels and it wll turn red once it goes wider than 768pixels?  You have orange inside of the media tag.

Comment: Nope. If i set it to @media (max-width:767px) { .my-class{color:purple} } Then that would work for media up until 767px wide.

Comment: Not sure if I should make this a new question but another site I was looking at, http://www.socalmeatcollective.com, had a problem with mobile and I can't get the CSS to adjust even if I use (at)media.  What would you do if (at)media was not working?  If I view it using a mobile tester, the regular css would be used and the media would be ignored no matter what width I am using.  On socal, for example, it seems the container id can't be adjusted.

Comment: never mind, figured out the problem with socal....apparently I had to move my (at)media style edits to the bottom of all the css styles.  so i put the sttle tag right above the </head> tag which made the (at)media style edits a priority.